# Blurry text and incorrect colors when printing PVC cards

Tags: printer

As described [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564433/blurry-text-when-generating-and-printing-an-id-card), I am generating ID cards and the dynamic text I insert appears so blurry that I have to use a bold font for it to be begrudgingly accepted. Also, the color is so off when printing, that I have to set the image's color higher (e.g., if I want to print orange, I almost have to make the image red).

What should I take a look at in the ID card printer's configuration for the printed color to be correct? Is this a normal behavior when printing `PVC` cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of these devices use thermal transfer, and do each colour (CYMK) separately. The colour transfer ribbons might be misaligned.

That aside, the colour reproduction of these devices is, at best, inaccurate.

Comment: We talked to the creative team and they're helping us with the color alignment indeed.